# Users' Preferred Default Table Row Count

Tags: data-tables, best-practice

I'm designing a data table with results that may be in the thousands. I am wondering if there is a preferred amount of results that display on first page load (10, 20, etc.?). The user may change the amount after the page loads. We're using React so there isn't a big delay to go to the next results.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a standard answer because it's going to depend on how much data your user needs in order to fulfill their task. They might only need a "top 10" glance, or in other cases, 200 rows might have valuable information.

**Analytics is your friend.** If you have access to an analytics platform (even user session playback), you can see how many times users are changing the number of results they wish to see, and how many pages they're looking at in the pager (you might need to tag the components in order to start collecting data).

Watch this data for 2 weeks (unless you have very little traffic, in which case, you'll need longer), then approximate the size of the dataset that they're consuming; that can give you an idea of a good default.

Comment: That's a great answer, thanks very much. We will use our data to average out the row count after a couple of months of use. Why didn't I think of that? :).